# htaccess url re-styling image url to seo friendly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently using htaccess to force to use **index.php** file. like given below.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In current website it has some uploaded contents like

- **uploads/item/11.jpg**
- **uploads/item/12.jpg**
- **uploads/item/13.jpg**

I wanted to re re-write it like.

- **uploads/item/11.jpg** => **uploads/item/11-itemName11whatEver.jpg**
- **uploads/item/12.jpg** => **uploads/item/12-itemName12whatEver.jpg**
- **uploads/item/13.jpg** => **uploads/item/13-itemName13whatEver.jpg**

Can anyone help me to find `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` for this.

> **Updated**

Updated htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} uploads-
    RewriteRule ^uploads-([^/]+)-([0-9]+)-[^.]+\.([a-z]+)$ uploads/$1/$2.$3 [L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This helps me to make the URL look like

> **www.store45.loc/uploads-item-11-sample-watch.jpg**

Comment: What is the URL you want to show in browser?

Comment: @anubhava i wanted to show "site.com/uploads/item/11-itemName11whatEver.jpg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} uploads-
RewriteRule ^uploads-([^/]+)-([0-9]+)-[^.]+\.([a-z]+)$ uploads/$1/$2.$3 [L,NC]
```